# Prevent HTML input field to allow backticks (`) and followed by any other char than a number

Tags: javascript, html, input

I have an HTML input as numeric, it doesn't allow anything but numbers except for the typical "e" or dots. I tried different strategies by keyCode to avoid these chars and they worked but can not escape the backtick (`) since when it's pressed then is captured after it was already printed and the key pressed after this one is not filtered and I end up with "234+" or any char I pressed.

Actual result: Even when I filter keys other than numbers by regex on event keyDown, if I press key "`" (backtick) it waits for a key to ve pressed and allows others than numbers.

Expected: Just need my input field to support only positive numbers, no "e", no ".", no ",", no "-", anything else.

Comment: I think the event `input` is a better approach than `keyup` and `keydown` events.

Comment: If you're preventing characters from being entered by using the key pressed you also need to consider that any character can be entered using ctrl+v

Comment: Have you considered trying the HTML5 input pattern attribute? https://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_input_pattern.asp
Note that both this, and javascript only validate client side, and can be easily disabled by a savvy user. You should also have server side validation

Comment: @ErikBaars I was literally about to suggest the same.

Comment: Sounds like you could need an inputmask.

Comment: Its safe at server side since I never allow to save this inputs, but would like to either allow to input them. But problem is the backtick, since is not caught, or is captured but as soon as the user press +,- or . its added due to the behaviour  of this key that after pressed waits for a bowel to be pressed: à, ò.